# Connected object instanciation

Tags: python, object, instantiation

I have written this code to instantiate a net ("noeud" means "node" in french) :

```
class Noeud():
  def __init__(self, tableaux_ptrs_noeuds) :
    self.ptr_noeud_suivant = ptr_noeud_suivant


A = Noeud([D, H, K])
D = Noeud([A, G, H])
F = Noeud([K, L])
G = Noeud([D, H, J, M])
H = Noeud([A, D, G, K, M])
J = Noeud([G, L, M])
K = Noeud([A, F, H, L, M])
L = Noeud([F, J, K, M])
M = Noeud([G, H, J, K, L])
```

But I get an error because A needs D H and K and there aren't defined yet. How can I solve this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: The best way is to rethink your class design so that nodes can be added/linked later, after initialization.  Then, create all your nodes ahead of time and go back and link them in the way you want.  There's no way for A to make use of objects that don't yet exist.

Comment: Thanks for your response ;) but, sorry, I don't get it, how do I have to redesign the class? I'm new with classes... If you respond not in a comment, I can give you reputation and write that it's resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BrenBarn is describing something like this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connections = []

    def connectNodes(self, nodes):
        self.connections += nodes

A = Node()
D = Node()
F = Node()
G = Node()
H = Node()
J = Node()
K = Node()
L = Node()
M = Node()
N = Node()

A.connect([D, H, K])
D.connect([A, G, H])
F.connect([K, L])
# and so on.
```

Comment: Sorry for switching languages on you - my French is a little nonexistent.

Comment: Ahah, I still have understood, it wasn't too complicated ;) thanks for your response